# C++ Pointer to pointer explanation in this code

Tags: c++, pointers

I am having a hard time understanding this code below:

```
char **strarray = new char*[120];

for(int i = 0; i < max; i++)
{
    strarray[i] = new char[120];
    cout << "Enter element: ";
    cin >> strarray[i];
}
```

What does this line mean? **char **strarray = new char*[120];**
Can someone please explain this. Thank you.

Comment: That's impossible: it should be `char **strarray=new char[120];` (without an asterisk after _new char_).

Comment: @ForceBru No, you're quite wrong.

Comment: @juanchopanza, ow, yep, these are pointers! Now I see.

Comment: It means someone wishes they were writing C. Use `std::vector<std::string>` to avoid memory leaks, buffer overflow, and worse.

Answer (score 0):

```
char **strarray = new char*[120];
```

allocates memory for an array of 120 pointers to `char`. You then allocate for each individual array element (each pointer to `char`) 120 characters, then read a string into it. Note that the last `120` has nothing to do with the size `120` of the initial array of pointers to `char`, so you could have used a different size in the `for` loop.

A good way of realizing what you're doing is to use a `typedef`

```
typedef char* pchar;
pchar* strarray = new pchar[120]; // can see the type here more transparently
```

Answer (score 0):

> What does this line mean?
>
> ```
> char **strarray = new char*[120];
> ```

It allocates an array of `120 char*` objects from the heap and lets `strarray` point to the allocated memory.

Answer (score 0):

`char **` means a pointer to a pointer to `char`.

`char* [120]` means an array of 120 pointers to `char`.

`char **strarray = new char*[120];` means allocate memory for 120 pointers to `char` and store it in `strarray`.

However, this just allocates memory for the *pointers*; there isn't any memory to store the strings themselves, hence why they are allocated later.